# context.response.print doesnt print the output

Tags: debugging, crystal-lang

is there any something wrong with dynamic hash definition ?, why the response print doesnt give me the output, but when i give a comment to the first line, the response print sending a output

```
res.headers.each { |k, v| context.response.headers[k] = v }
context.response.print res.body
```

my full code : https://github.com/codenoid/lemmehand/blob/master/server.cr
thanks ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you want to do? You got compressed stream that automatically decompressed and send it as is without updating of encoding headers.

minimal working example:

```
server = HTTP::Server.new(port.to_i) do |context|
  params = {} of String => String
  context.request.query_params.each do |k, v|
    params[k] = v
  end
  if params.has_key?("get")
    HTTP::Client.get(params["get"]) do |res|
      context.response.content_type = res.content_type.to_s
      context.response.status_code = res.status_code
      res.headers.each do |k, v|
        next if k == "Content-Encoding"
        next if k == "Content-Length"
        next if k == "Transfer-Encoding"
        context.response.headers[k] = v
      end
      context.response.print res.body_io.gets_to_end
    end
  else
    context.response.content_type = "text/plain"
    context.response.print "you must use GET method,ex.  yourserver.com/?get=http://yoururl.com/"
  end
end
```